# How would HIVE queries efficiently find data stored in avro format?

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, avro

We have a large number of relatively small incoming files for analysis, all with slight variations on the available columns. We are converting them into avro format and maintaining a master union schema file across all the data files. We are then creating a HIVE table and exposing it for query.

I can't help but think that something is not right with this picture. How would a query be able to identify which individual file or files to access to fetch any small data subset? Would it not require every query to read every file and search for the queried data? This seems extremely inefficient.
One option would be to start combining these files, but even with files exactly the same size as the Hadoop block size, we would have a large number of files.

Now, I have complete information on the content of each file. They are tagged by dates, so if I was to manually look for data, I would know exactly which files to go access. How do I build that knowledge into the HIVE interface?

Answer (score 0):

I believe my question is not unique to AVRO file formats and is a general issue when creating HIVE tables on any underlying external data which is fragmented into multiple files. If you do a google search asking the same question about HIVE and multiple files, you will find that the best approach to solve this is to create partitions in the table. Each partition will guide the queries to only go across the relevant files.

The trick is to correctly design how you store your files into sub-folders and assign appropriate partitions.